# shimano CS-5600 compatible rear hub and freehub body

Tags: cassette, hub, rear-wheel, freehub

What rear hubs and/or freehub bodies are compatible with a Shimano 105 5600 10-speed 12-25T cassette?

Comment: Shimano freehub bodies are compatible with shimano cassettes (and shimano-compatible off-brand freehub bodies, and shimano-compatible cassettes)   That part is straightforward.  Your hub to freehub-body interface depends a lot more on what hub it is.  There are dozens of different connection systems for freehub body to wheel hub.   What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm thinking of buying a new rear hub

Comment: @steeef - note that buying a complete wheel is a usually better idea in cost and quality than buying the hub then getting the wheel built yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a rim-braked road-bike, any rear hub that is Shimano 10/11 speed compatible will take your cassette and all other 10-speed Shimano road cassettes.

Just be aware that you need a 1.85mm spacer that goes on a freehub 11-speed body before you put on the cassette. Without the spacer the 10s cassette will move sideways.

Comment: Also hub width. Road hubs are 130 mm OLD and mountain are 135. Something to think about when picking the hub wrt the frame choice.

Comment: @Batman: 105 -5600 is road and most certainly 130mm if not disc braked. That's why I mentioned 'rim-braked'. I own a CX-bike with the disc version and 135mm spacing. The fitting of a cassette is identical on both hubs.

Comment: It's a bit of a weird question. The guy seems to have the cassette but not the hub or wheel. The point comes up in whether he has a frame or not, where this matters. =)

Comment: @Batman I have everything. I just want to buy a new rear hub